# How to create a std::map of constant values which is still accessible by the [] operator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constants, c++03

I need a std:map data structure that is read only, which means I have to fill it once with data and then only read those values, never change them or add additional ones.

My non-const version looks like this:

```
//in .h
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, int> myMap;
void initMap();

//in .cpp
#include "foo.h"

void initMap() {
  myMap["Keys"] = 42;
}
```

Then I'd call `initMap()` once in my code and be done.

Now I've read several questions here already and it seems non-trivial to achieve const-ness for the map.

Making it a `std::map<std::string, const int>` won't allow me to fill it in the `initMap()`.
Filling it with a non-const temp and the copy constructor on definition doesn't work either, as the copy constructor doesn't easily take the non-const version as input.

Making it a `const std::map<std::string, int>` (which I could fill with a non-const copy during definition) would disable the use of the `[]` operator for value access.

So is there a way to achieve (value) const-ness and initialize the structure (preferably in the header file)?

BTW: Neither C++0x nor C++11 nor `boost::` is an option.

Comment: Do you want "a std:map data structure that is read only", or do you want a map with read-only elements?

Comment: I want the former, but I can live with the later if this keeps me the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couldn't you use the `insert()` method available for `std::map`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Edit : (solution) `myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, const int>("Keys", 42));`

As far as I understand it, the reason why this works is because the constructor for the pair, `pair (const first_type& a, const second_type& b)`, initializes its members `first` and `second` using the constructors for `first_type` and `second_type`, taking `a` and `b` as their respective parameter.

With the solution you were trying to use, my comprehension is that `myMap["Keys"] = 42;` initializes the member `second` of the `map` (of type `const int`) using the default constructor for `int`. Then a value is attempted to be assigned to that member. As this is done outside the constructor of the class `map`, the `const` declaration makes this impossible.

With the solution using `insert()`, the members are initialized in the constructor of the `pair`. Thus they can be declared `const`. The same operation is done when the `pair` is copied to the `map`.

Comment: Expand your answer to be way more verbatim and actually answer my question and I accept is as right. Indeed, using my own code example above, replacing `myMap["Keys"] = 42;` by `myMap.insert(std::make_pair("Keys", 42))` will work for a `std::map<std::string, const int>`. But I have no idea why this one works and the other one not.

Comment: And I just verified, it correctly gives me a compiler error on write access (`myMap["Keys"] = 23;`) while still allowing read access (`std::cout << myMap["Keys"]`).

Comment: @Chaos_99 Sorry. I would've preferred to write it as a comment, but I'm not yet allowed to.

Comment: @Chaos_99 I added more in-depth explanations to my answer. This applies to the solution that I gave as an example. If you use `myMap.insert(std::make_pair("Keys", 42))`, the principle is the same, but the initialization of the `const int` is only done in the constructor of `map`, since the type of the members of the `pair` will be whatever it decides is most fitting for `"Keys"` and `42`.

Answer (score 11):

While this is not possible for you, others who wants to do this and that have a C++11 compatible compiler, could use [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization):

```
std::map<std::string, const int> myMap = {
    { "keys", 42 }
};
```

---

Oh and by the way, don't *define* the map in the header file. Instead *declare* it as `extern` in the header file, then define it in the source file.

Comment: I've edited the original question. No C++0x also means no C++11. But you're absolutely right about the declare/define. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to write your own, wrapping the
standard map class:

```
template <typename KeyType, typename MappedType, typename CmpType>
class ConstantMap
{
    typedef std::map<KeyType, MappedType, CmpType> Impl;
    Impl myImpl;
public:
    typedef Impl::value_type value_type;

    template <ForwardIterator>
    ConstantMap( ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end, CmpType cmp = CmpType() )
        : myImpl( begin, end, cmp )
    {
    }

    //  necessary if [] is not going to work for missing keys
    bool contains( KeyType const& key ) const
    {
        return myImpl.find( key ) != myImpl.end();
    }

    MappedType const& operator[]( KeyType const& key ) const
    {
        Impl::const_iterator elem = myImpl.find( key );
        if ( elem == myImpl.end() ) {
            //  Not found, do what you want (maybe throw an exception)
        }
        return elem.second;
    }
};
```

You can initialze the map by passing it iterators to a sequence
of anything which can convert to `value_type`.

Depending on your needs, you may want to add additional
forwarding typedefs, functions, etc.  If you're using C++11, you
may also want to create a constructor which can use a list
initializer.

Comment: Thanks for the wrapper class example code. I'm sure it may come handy to a lot of people searching for a custom map class. But I'll take @Matzar s solution as long as const-ness is my only need.

Answer (score 1):

If the `map` can't mutate, you should use `const map<string, int>`, and not `map<string, const int>`: the second version allows insertion and deletion of objects.

Sadly, you are going to have to lose the `[]` operator; C++ doesn't have an `ImmutableMap`, or something like that. However, `std::map::at` and `std::map::find` aren't too bad...

Comment: If it's between the [] operator and insertion/deletion, I'd go with insertion/deletion. Not using something by convention is easier to 'sell' to other devs then clunky access syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Something much simpler which has a **smaller footprint and is faster**:

```
static const int MyMapData[] = {
    42      // index 0 is mapped to "key"
};

struct MyMap
{
    const int& operator[](std::string key) const
    {
        switch (key) {
            case "Keys": return MyMapData[0];

            default: return NotANumber;     // Return 0 and raise an assertion, or return "Not a Number".
        }
    }
};
```

Easy to maintain, no use of templates, no use of boost libraries and compilable everywhere.

Comment: Might work for this simple example, but running a switch statement with thousands of options is probably not faster than a std::map access.