# Error while assigning a pair value to a map key

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

This is excerpt from my code:

```
std::map<int, std::pair< const int, const std::vector<POINT_3d> > > m_srcHitData;
void addHit( const int edgeId, const int hit )
{
  m_srcHitData[edgeId] = std::make_pair( hit, std::vector<POINT_3d>() );
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> ```
>    stl_pair.h(180): error: no operator "=" matches these operands
>                 operand types are: const std::vector<POINT_3d, std::allocator<POINT_3d>> = const std::vector<POINT_3d, std::allocator<POINT_3d>>
>               second = __p.second;
>                      ^
>     detected during instantiation of "std::pair<_T1, _T2> &std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(const std::pair<_U1, _U2> &)
> ```

What does that mean? I tried different approaches but still getting this or similar error. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using `m_srcHitData[edgeId] = std::make_pair( hit, std::vector<POINT_3d>() );` try using `m_srcHitData[edgeId].insert( std::make_pair( hit, std::vector<POINT_3d>() );` and see if this works or gives you a different compiler error. Hmm now that I thought about that insert may not work on `m_srcHitDat[idx]` same issue as einpoklum stated because of constness.

Comment: @Francis You did not actually mean m_srcHitData[edgeId].insert() , right? It should be m_srcHitData.insert ( pair (edgeId, ...) ). This works, thanks!

Comment: well when I was answering I didn't have my IDE open. So I was trying to go off of memory... refer to my answer as the appropriate way to construct the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `m_srcHitData[edgeId]` is a pair with a `const` vector member. You can't simply assign to it, because that means assigning to the `const` vector, which is not possible...

As for what you can do about it, see:

[How to create a std::map of constant values which is still accessible by the [] operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16708618/1593077)

As @FrancisCugler suggests, that could be, for example, writing:

```
m_srcHitData[edgeId].insert( std::make_pair( hit, std::vector<POINT_3d>() );
```

However, if your vectors are long, you might not actually want to copy all that data around.

Answer (score 1):

This part in your code kind of looks ugly...

```
std::map<int, std::pair< const int, const std::vector<POINT_3d> > > m_srcHitData;
```

You could try restructuring your code a little.

```
struct Pair {
    unsigned int key_;
    std::vector<POINT_3d> points_;

    Pair() {} // Empty Default
    Pair( const unsigned int& key, const std::vector<POINT_3d>& points ) :
        key_(key),
        points_( points ) 
    {}
};
```

Then...

```
std::map<unsigned, Pair> m_srcHitData;

void addHit( const int edgeId, const int hit ) {
    m_srcHitData[edgeId] = Pair( hit, std::vector<POINT_3d>() );
}
```

I made this short program to simulate a similar structure only I used `strings` in place of your `std::vector<POINT_3d>`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct Pair {
    unsigned key_;
    std::string value_;

    Pair() {}
    Pair( const unsigned int& key, const std::string& value ) :
        key_( key ),
        value_( value ) {}
};

class MyClass {
public:
    std::map<unsigned, Pair> myMap_;

    void addValue( const unsigned int& key, const std::string& value ) {
        myMap_[key] = Pair( key, value );
    }
};

int main() {

    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.addValue( 1, "Hello" );
    myClass.addValue( 2, "World" );

    typedef std::map<unsigned, Pair>::iterator Iter;
    Iter it = myClass.myMap_.begin();

    for ( ; it != myClass.myMap_.end(); ++it ) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << " Pair-Key: " << it->second.key_ << " Pair-value: " << it->second.value_ << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

You can use the above, except substitute your objects of `vector<T>` with the `strings`.

I also used public interface on both the `struct` and `class` for simplicity of demonstration. Normally the container in the `class` would be either `protected` or `private` with accessory functions.

**EDIT** This is to help construct the map first. Once you have the map working then you can modify it to add in the `const` storage types if needed, but they can be tricky to work with. Refer to the link in einpoklum's answer.

If you are working with the newer versions of C++ you can change these lines of code:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned, Pair>::iterator Iter;
Iter it = myClass.myMap_.begin();
```

into this:

```
auto it = myClass.myMap_.begin();
```